# Key strokes to enter chars in text boxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, char

How do I know programmatically if a char like `'@'` needs to be entered in a text box with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down ?

This is the list for <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>: `² ³ { [ ] } \ @ € ~ | µ`
And a longer list for <kbd>Shift</kbd>: `°!"§$%&/()=?*'>;:_`, letters and more

`Char.IsUpper(...)` helps me with the letters. But how do I solve this for the rest ? I want to be able to check them all correctly and I would like to make the system do if for me if possible.

In the end I will be sending those key strokes via [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
*(I use WinForms.)*

Comment: Is that winforms or WPF?

Comment: @KajalSinha I use WinForms. Not sure why this might be important.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to accomplish, but you can cast the char to int so you get the decimal representation of that char. That representation is of course unique for each character. For example the ASCII character @ has a decimal value of 64. Can you doe something with that??

Comment: Simulating keyboard input to automate a UI is not ever not a mistake. Use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) if you aim for a reliable solution.

Comment: Sigh. Input faking XY problem again. Almost certainly you have chosen the wrong solution to your problem, whatever that problem happens to be.

Comment: So this is what you do ? You down vote questions whose answers provide knowledge for something you don't agree with ? Both your comments are wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Consider sending them by sending a `WM_CHAR` instead of going down to the key abstraction level.

Comment: Using keys obviously can't work in the general case, since most characters aren't even available on most keyboard layouts. For example what do you want to do if you encounter `ü` but the keyboard layout is American? And what if if the input requires deadkeys? If you really need to work with keys, ALT+Number is the only thing I can think of, but I'm not sure it's possible to use this with codes >255.

Comment: I don't see where votes come into this. I've not voted. And if I had it would be my choice. You are not going about this the right way. Step 1 is to tell us about your problem.

Comment: Your question: *"How do I programmatically enter text into a text box?"* - Answer: "Use UI Automation." - Your response: *"The answer is wrong, upvote my question, because, well, you'll see when I find time to disclose the question in its entirety."*

Comment: @IInspectable _"How do I programmatically enter text into a text box?"_ Is **not** my question.

Comment: Well, true. **Your** question was way more convoluted: *"How do I know which modifiers need to be held down to enter a particular character into a text box. I need to know so that I can automate an UI by simulating input - poorly - through `keybd_event`."* If this question was asked with a goal different from *How do I programmatically enter text into a text box*, I'm afraid your poor choice of solutions may not be the worst of your problems.

Comment: @IInspectable It's taxing to fight off XY problem poachers. There is no XY problem here. **I'm sure!** And I'm glad I found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24530076/1442225) to my question. There is no need for that much discussion. I just used `text boxes` and `keybd_event` examples to ease the understanding of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. [VkKeyScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the key.
*([VkKeyScanEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for KeyboardLayouts etc.)*

**Some test code:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] chars = "²³{[]}\\@€~|µ   °!`\"§$%&/()=?*'>;:_".ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine("char\talt\tcontrol\tshift" + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = chars[i];
        short vksc = VkKeyScan(ch);

        bool alt = (vksc & 1024) == 1024;
        bool control = (vksc & 512) == 512;
        bool shift = (vksc & 256) == 256;

        Console.WriteLine(ch + "\t" + alt + "\t" + control + "\t" + shift);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Which has `vksc == -1` in the case that there is no key for that char. So it only works for a tiny fraction of characters.

Comment: This doesn't even work for all characters the keyboard layout supports. For example I can enter `ü` by typing `¨` as a deadkey followed by `u`. It's failing completely for Asian keyboard layouts.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It does what I need. Works for the keyboard in front of me. When I need to figure out keyboard layouts I'll look into it. And at this point I don't care about keyboard layouts. Nor did I when I asked.

Comment: Whilst you asked the question, it is now owned by Stack Overflow. Which means that although you don't care how hacky your solution is, we do. For the benefit of future readers, @CodeInChaos is explaining the limitations of the approach espoused by this answer. That's fine. You have what you want, and future readers will be well informed to judge whether or not this answer is useful to them.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the key modifiers using following

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
{
    //control key 
}

if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Alt)
{
    //Alt
}
```

Source links

[Determine Which Modifier Key Was Pressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yazd4ct6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Modifier Key Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Those two if blocks look identical to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question. The question is about how to map characters to keys or perhaps how to simulate input of a character. This answer is about detecting key presses.

Comment: First version had two identical `if` statements. So you updated the code and made sure, the expression of the second `if` statement is never `true`. Considering that the comment in the first `if` clause is also wrong, we can conclude that now, after your edit, **everything** is wrong.